# Created a Log In and Log out Session with php but i am having trouble with the Log out

Tags: php, session, authentication, logout

Everything works fine like the Log in and then that changing to a page and saying you are logged in and i can straight away move on with my work but now if i want to Log out and click Log out, it does log me out but it shows me an Error saying this

"Notice: Use of undefined constant PHPSESSID - assumed 'PHPSESSID' in E:\3 Web Programming\wamp\www\public_html\logout.php on line 12"

this is my php script for the Log out

```
<?php

    echo "Logged out scuccessfully";

    session_start();
    session_destroy();
    setcookie(PHPSESSID,session_id(),time()-1);

?>
```

also does anyone know how after I logged out the page refers back to the Log In page still by saying "You have successfully logged out"

Please ask if you need to know anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `setcookie(PHPSESSID,session_id(),time()-1);` you could just use: `session_regenerate_id(true);` this creates a new id and updates the associated cookie.

To redirect a user to a logged-out page, you could use:

```
 header('Location: /pageafterlogout.php');
```